# who disable overlay of FragmentTabHost of my ListView in android?

Tags: android, listview, android-fragmentactivity, android-support-library

Im using v4 FragmentActivity to create v4 FragmentTabHost, my problem is the FragmentTabHost is overlaying my ListView, how to disable the overlay tabhost from listview?

pics: http://prntscr.com/2lg8lj

Homepage.class

```
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTabHost;
import android.view.Window;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class HomePage extends FragmentActivity {

    private FragmentTabHost fragTabHost;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.home_page);

        fragTabHost = (FragmentTabHost) findViewById(android.R.id.tabhost);
        fragTabHost.setup(this, getSupportFragmentManager(),
                R.id.realTabContent);

        fragTabHost.addTab(fragTabHost.newTabSpec("today").setIndicator("Today"),
                Today.class, null);
        fragTabHost.addTab(fragTabHost.newTabSpec("yesterday").setIndicator("Yesterday"),
                Yesterday.class, null);
        fragTabHost.addTab(fragTabHost.newTabSpec("preview").setIndicator("Preview"),
                Preview.class, null);
        fragTabHost.addTab(fragTabHost.newTabSpec("info").setIndicator("Info"),
                Info.class, null);
    }
}
```

home_page.xml

```
<android.support.v4.app.FragmentTabHost xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_height="0dip"
            android:layout_weight="0" />

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/realTabContent"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dip"
            android:layout_weight="1" />
    </LinearLayout>

</android.support.v4.app.FragmentTabHost>
```

How to disable the overlay of the FragmentTabHost to my listview which is inside ListFragment.class?

Answer (score 0):

In you layout xml file, you need to specify the `TabWidget`:

```
<android.support.v4.app.FragmentTabHost xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <!-- ADD THIS SECTION -->
        <TabWidget
            android:id="@android:id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="top" >
        </TabWidget>

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_height="0dip"
            android:layout_weight="0" />

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/realTabContent"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dip"
            android:layout_weight="1" />
    </LinearLayout>

</android.support.v4.app.FragmentTabHost>
```